# Knowledge database

Tags: knowledge, salesforce2salesforce, help

My company managed to made salesforce customization for the sales agents, but not all sales agents are aware for all the scenarios that can occur.

So, because of that I am trying to find app or something that by importing few key words will give them information about what they need to do.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Darko

Comment: Are you looking for a Sales Coach type application or something more?

Comment: yes, free if possible